# ¿Almacenar datos en una lista y no reemplazarlos?. C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Problema: Tengo una función que la uso para buscar un dato en una lista funciona bien, pero cuando mando a llamar a esta función mas de una vez en lugar de asignar otro espacio para traerme ambos resultados solo me lo reemplaza, Existe alguna manera de que si mando a ejecutar dos o mas veces la funcion me regrese todos los datos y no solo me regrese el ultimo?

```
Lugar de donde la mando a llamar:
for(int i =0; i< txtB.LineCount; i++)
            {
                linea[i] = txtB.GetLineText(i);
                if(linea[i] != null)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(linea[i], @"^>int|>Entero\s+[a-z](1,15)(\s+:\s+\d(0,32000))*;$"))
                    {
                        dynamic datos = new List<Complete>();
                        datos = Tsimbolos.BuscarToken(">int",i);
                        TokensData.ItemsSource = datos;
                    }
                }
            }

Funcion: 
 public List<Complete> BuscarToken(string argumento, int linea)
    {
        foreach (var word in tSimbolos)
        {
            if (word.Token1 == argumento)
            {
                dynamic datos = new List<Complete>();
                datos.Add(new Complete(word.Token1, word.Tipo1, (linea + 1).ToString(), word.ID_Token1.ToString()));
                return datos;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

Clase del complete:
 public class Complete
{
    private string token;
    private string tipo;
    private string linea;
    private string idTk;
    public Complete(string token, string tipo, string linea, string idTk)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.linea = linea;
        this.idTk = idTk;
    }

    public string Token { get => token; set => token = value; }
    public string Tipo { get => tipo; set => tipo = value; }
    public string Linea { get => linea; set => linea = value; }
    public string IdTk { get => idTk; set => idTk = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta dentro de tus metodos, ya que estos mismos instancian de nuevo las listas cada vez que los ejecutas.

Quita tu `List<Complete>` dentro del metodo.

```
dynamic datos = new List<Complete>();
```

Lugar de donde la mando a llamar:

```
 for(int i =0; i< txtB.LineCount; i++)
        {
            linea[i] = txtB.GetLineText(i);
            if(linea[i] != null)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(linea[i], @"^>int|>Entero\s+[a-z](1,15)(\s+:\s+\d(0,32000))*;$"))
                {

                    datos = Tsimbolos.BuscarToken(">int",i);
                    TokensData.ItemsSource = datos;
                }
            }
        }
```

Funcion:

```
 public List<Complete> BuscarToken(string argumento, int linea)
    {
        foreach (var word in tSimbolos)
        {
            if (word.Token1 == argumento)
            {
               datos.Add(new Complete(word.Token1, word.Tipo1, (linea + 1).ToString(), word.ID_Token1.ToString()));
                return datos;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```